# how to pass alerted values in javascript into another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i need to know how to pass the alerted values in javascript into a aspx page as query string this is what i have tried:

```
  function SelectedRow() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btnprint', function () {
        var row = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
        var rowtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
        alert(rowtext);
        window.open("http://10.19.13.67/ReworkLabels/Default.aspx?rowtext=" + rowtext, "my window");
        return rowtext;
    });   
}

 I am able to pass the variables into the aspx but the output looks like this:
http://10.19.13.67/ReworkLabels/Default.aspx?rowtext=7ECN1227-001SAVSS0.85B13707116-1232%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20917418-060
what i need the output to be like is 7ECN1227-000,SAVSS0.85B,1370,7116-1232,20917418-060
```

Comment: Pass it as a GET parameter to the Default.aspx url .

Comment: Query string? Sessions? cookie? ajax? html5 local storage? Choose your preferred option

Comment: how do you go about using all the above suggestion since an not sure on how to go about doing it. An example would be nice